# Parsing string with regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a string like this:

```
Addadafafa/DHello/p2324141142DsddDsdsds/Dgood/p23323
```

For those who didn't notice, the text I want to keep is always between `/D` and `/p`.
I've tried to parse it using regex but I couldn't do it for all the string.
It always kept the first or last word.

How can I keep a new string with all of the words between `/D` and `/p` from the former string?

Expected output:

```
hello good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    string str = "Addadafafa/DHello/p2324141142DsddDsdsds/Dgood/p23323";
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"/D(\w+)/p");
    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(str);
    string result = "";
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result += match.Result("$1") + " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Or:

```
    string str = "Addadafafa/DHello/p2324141142DsddDsdsds/Dgood/p23323";
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?!/D)[^D]\w+(?=/p)");
    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(str);
    string result = "";
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result += match.Value + " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string input = "Addadafafa/DHello/p2324141142DsddDsdsds/Dgood/p23323";
var parts = Regex.Matches(input, "/D(.+?)/p")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                 .ToList();

string finalStr = String.Join(" ", parts); //If you need this.
```

Comment: The key here is the non-greedy quantifier `+?`.  Without it, it would match `Hello/p2324141142DsddDsdsds/Dgood`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = input.Split(new[] {"/D", "/p"}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Where((w, i) => (i & 1) == 1);
```